# Excel VBA Update cell value in table based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which gets data via a URL. The table has the following structure

```
Issue Key   Assignee   Status         Tester   Developer
1           John       In Progress             John
2           Peter      In Testing     Peter    May
```

Tester and Developer columns are automatically filled when Status is changed.

```
If Status = In Progress, Developer = Assignee (in this case, John)
If Status = In Testing, Tester = Peter (in this case, Peter)
```

We have No Else part in If statement

I build a macro to get this thing as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const STATUS_INPROGRESS = "In Progress"

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim x As Long

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("S70")

If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("S70").DataBodyRange) _
  Is Nothing) Then
    For x = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        With tbl.ListRows(x)
            If .Range(1, 3).Value2 = STATUS_INPROGRESS Then 'Developer colum
                .Range(1, 5).Value2 = .Range(1, 2).Value2 
            End If
        End With
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

The macro check if the status is In Progress, it will assign a value from Assignee to Developer. It throws an error every time I made a change on table range, the error is "**method value2 of object range failed**"
It happens on the assigned part.

```
.Range(1, 5).Value2 = .Range(1, 2).Value2
```

If I changed to `.Value`, the same error happens. Could you help me with this?

Comment: What if you use `Value`?

Comment: It's same error

Comment: You should disable events before making changes. What's in those cells?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace all `ActiveSheet` with `Me` it might be a different sheet. `ActiveSheet` is the sheet that has focus (is on top) while `Me` is the sheet the event and `Target` is in.
2. `.Range(1, 3)` is no valid syntax you probably meant to use `.Cells(1, 3)`.

   The [Range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) needs an address (or 2) like `Range("A1")` or `Range("A1", "C5")` which is the same as `Range("A1:C5")`.

   If you want to use row/column number you must use the [Range.Cells property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells) or [Worksheet.Cells property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells): `Cells(row, column)`.
3. Before you write values into cells, you must disable events and enable them afterwards. Otherwise your write action will trigger the change event again and again.

   ```
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   ' your code to write values

   Application.EnableEvents = True
   ```

So you end up with something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Const STATUS_INPROGRESS As String = "In Progress"

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("S70")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS 'in case of error make sure events get re-enabled or they will stay off until you close Excel

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("S70").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
            With tbl.ListRows(iRow)
                If .Cells(1, 3).Value2 = STATUS_INPROGRESS Then 'Developer colum
                    .Cells(1, 5).Value2 = .Cells(1, 2).Value2 
                End If
            End With
        Next iRow 
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'raise error message otherwise it will be silent and you never notice any errors
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When I narrow down the observe range changes from the data body to a single column, it works as expected. But I will try your solution tomorrow.

Comment: @SteveLam Yes, because then you edit values outside the observed range and the event doesn't trigger itself over and over. But even if it works I *highly* recommend to `Application.EnableEvents = False` before editing any cells in the event (and don't forget to enable it in the end or in case of errors).

Comment: It says Subscript out of range. Could you show me what it is?